# Azure: The agent has received a shutdown signal. This can happen when the agent service is stopped, or a manually started agent is canceled

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Build fails and receives this error:

> The agent has received a shutdown signal. This can happen when the
>   agent service is stopped, or a manually started agent is canceled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out that the subscription ran out and got downgraded to "Free" which has a build timeout of 30mins. If you get this error, check the duration for 30 minutes as that might be the same case.

There are probably other causes for this error as well.